# Calculating Idle Time at a metro station

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataset, logic

In a college project we have been given a metro dataset of the city Los Angeles:
The dataset contains 1.6 million rows of transaction data, such as (transaktion_id, start_time, start_station_id, end_time, end_station_id, bike_id)

we have to calculate the idle time of each station, that mean the time between a bike return and next bike rent.

firstly i wrote this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
csv_file = '../Data_Cleanup/outCSV/Clean_Metro_Set.csv'
metro = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
metro['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(metro['start_time'])

metro ['end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(metro['end_time'])

metro = metro.sort_values(by='start_time')
metro['idle_time'] = None

BigDict = {}  # Initialize an empty dictionary to store station IDs and end times

# Iterate through each row in the DataFrame
for i, row in metro.iterrows():
    current_start_station_id = metro.loc[i, "start_station_id"]
    current_end_station_id = metro.loc[i, "end_station_id"]
    current_start_time = metro.loc[i, "start_time"]
    current_end_time = metro.loc[i, "end_time"]

    try:
        # Check if current start time is greater than the stored end time for the start station ID
        if current_start_time > BigDict[str(current_start_station_id)]:
            # Calculate idle time as the difference between the current start time and the stored end time
            metro.at[i, "idle_time"] = current_start_time - BigDict[str(current_start_station_id)]
    except KeyError:
        pass

    # Store the current end time for the end station ID in BigDict
    try:
        if current_end_time > BigDict[str(current_end_station_id)]:
            BigDict[str(current_end_station_id)] = current_end_time
    except KeyError:
        BigDict[str(current_end_station_id)] = current_end_time
```

but then i realised it doesn't satisfy a specific case in there which is explained in the picture. the green marked time intervall (in the picture) should be considered idle, but in my code above it would just get replaced .
[image]

sample of the dataset: https://github.com/Sabaawi7/Code-with-Mo/blob/master/sample.csv

Below is a simplified version of the input

```
transaction_id,start_time, start_station_id, end_time, end_station_id
0,2017-01-01 10:00:00, 3027, 2017-01-01 10:10:00, 3027
1,2017-01-01 10:01:00, 3027, 2017-01-01 10:05:00, 3027
2,2017-01-01 10:03:00, 3027, 2017-01-01 10:20:00, 3027
3,2017-01-01 10:07:00, 3027, 2017-01-01 10:09:00, 3027
4,2017-01-01 10:12:00, 3027, 2017-01-01 10:23:00, 3027
```

Expected to have a column named "idle_time" where each row contains either "None", or the idle_time since last return of a bike at the same station id.
Expected Output

```
transaction_id,start_time, start_station_id, end_time, end_station_id,idle_time
0,2017-01-01 10:00:00, 3027, 2017-01-01 10:10:00, 3027,none
1,2017-01-01 10:01:00, 3027, 2017-01-01 10:05:00, 3027,none
2,2017-01-01 10:03:00, 3027, 2017-01-01 10:20:00, 3027,none
3,2017-01-01 10:07:00, 3027, 2017-01-01 10:09:00, 3027,0 days 00:02:00
4,2017-01-01 10:12:00, 3027, 2017-01-01 10:23:00, 3027,0 days 00:02:00
```

My Question is how to calculate this idle time in a decent computation time.
I would be happy about any tip or advice.

Comment: Could you provide the code that initialises the input, and could you add the data structure that is expected at the end, for the given example.

Comment: Please not in comments. Edit your question. Also if the code reads from an input file, then please share the content of the input file. Please don't post a link to an input file. Add it inside your question. A question should be self-contained.

Comment: Please add the exact expected output for the example input.

Comment: What should happen when there are two bikes at a station to choose from? Which one will be taken?

Comment: it doesnt actually matter, because the idle time is being calculated in relation to the station itself, no matter what bike is rented and/or returned

Comment: But in your expected output you have an idle time per transaction, not per station. Are you saying that is not the actual output that is expected?

Comment: the idle time explains how much time since last transaction (end_time) at the same station id has passed.

this example was only to simplify the input. the actual input has around 400 station ids, and a transaction may start at a station and end at a different station.

Comment: Surely an end time belongs to a particular bike, which once it is taken for a next trip is no longer available at that station. So that end time, even if it would still be the most recent end time cannot be used for a next departure. So obviously you are not looking for the most recent end time in general. And still my question remains unanswered: But in your expected output you have an idle time per transaction, not per station. Are you saying that is not the actual output that is expected?

Comment: We could continue this conversation, but I will pass.  It would all be easier if you would just quote the literal challenge that should explain and clarify any ambiguity.

Comment: Can you clearly define when a station is considered "idle"? A bike can be rented from and returned to different stations. How would you specify _"the time between a bike return and next bike rent"_?

Comment: For each station, create a list of events, where an event is either a *bike rent* or a *bike return*. Sort the list of events. Then for every *bike rent* event that's preceded by a *bike return* set the idle time to the difference in the event timestamps. For every *bike rent* that's not preceded by a *bike return* set the idle time to none.